# Conversion of infinite for loop to finite for loop

Tags: c

in C,how can we convert an infinite loop into finite loop without wrinting anything in syntax of for loop....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    a=1;
    a++;
    for( ; ; )
    {
       a<=10;
       printf("%d",a); 
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What is this point? Is this a homework/interview question?

Answer (score 8):

You could use `break` statement there.

This will exit the loop and start control beneath the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    for(;;)
       if ((++a) <= 10)
         printf("%d",a);
       else
         break;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I think this will execute just 9 times :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are asking here...

**EDIT**

```
int main()
{
   int a;
   a=0;
   for(;;)
   {
        if(a>10)
        break;
        printf("%d",a);
        a++
   }
   getch();
}
```

Comment: @Sakshi: Now try u can get the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Make a condition inside the loop where you want to end that..
Otherwise use **break** or **exit** like statements...

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    for(a=1 ; a<=10; a++)
    {
         printf("%d",a); 
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: i dont want 2 wrtte anything in for loop syntax

Comment: ok, then you should have used while loop but anyways, try this for loop: for(;;) { printf("%d", a); if (a == 10) { break; } a++; }

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    a=1;
    m:
    for(;;)
    {
         if(a<=10)
         {
      printf("%d\n",a); 
      a++;
      } 
      if(a<10)
      {
      goto m;
}
         }
         getch();
    }
```

Comment: `break`, as well as using other language features, is generally looked upon much more favourably than `goto`. Also, there is still an infinite loop here, since your `goto` just jumps back to a line before the `for` loop.